# Debugging aid for collecting objects from everywhere into a single scope

Tags: java

Today I faced a difficult problem where I needed to step through several totally unrelated classes, and I suspected (among others) an object aliasing problem somewhere deep in the framework layers.

In Eclipse, I had several breakpoints at which I could look at some of the objects and variables. But as soon as the frame finished, these variables would be gone. In addition, I wanted to relate objects from all over the system. And because I suspected an aliasing problem I wanted to see the Instance IDs. My first idea was to just right-click on a variable and add that object to the Watches, but that's not helpful. The watch expression would be evaluated each time anew in the then-current execution context.

Then I got creative. A global list of variables, that could solve my problem. I implemented this idea and added a nice and simple API that is targeted towards use in conditional breakpoints. I think this simple class will prove quite powerful since once you get creative, there's so many things this class can do:

- event tracing in real-time
- collecting data from different sources
- watching variables change (by using watch points)
- and probably many more I haven't thought off
- having a separate GUI to filter the captured variables during debugging, like in the Process Monitor from Sysinternals (this would require much more code though)

Here's the code:

```
package de.roland_illig.debug;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

/**
 * DebugVars remembers the given objects for use in a debugging session.
 * <p>
 * To use it, add a permanent watch for {@code DebugVars.get()}.
 * This will give access to all the remembered variables.
 * <p>
 * Not only can this class be used for remembering variables, it's
 * equally possible to create a trace log by just adding a string
 * instead of an arbitrary object.
 * <p>
 * Code that is writeable in the IDE can simply call:
 * <pre>    DebugVars.add(obj, "description");</pre>
 * <p>
 * Code that is read-only in the IDE can set a breakpoint with the
 * following condition:
 * <pre>    DebugVars.add(this, "the session state")</pre>
 * Since that method always returns {@code false}, the debugger will
 * never stop at that breakpoint but still evaluate the side effects.
 * <p>
 * In a long debugging session, it is possible to set a {@link #mark()},
 * and the next call to {@link #reset()} will discard all variables
 * that have been added after that mark. There can be several marks,
 * which allows for recording interesting objects while diving deep
 * into a call hierarchy. These two methods return {@code false} as
 * well, to be used in side-effect breakpoints.
 * <p>
 * Hint: for taking small notes during the debugging session, it is
 * possible to interactively modify the variable's description via
 * the Change Value menu item in the Variables view.
 * <p>
 * Note: all objects are remembered by reference, which means the
 * values shown here are their current values. These may be different
 * from the values they had at the time they were added.
 */
public final class DebugVars {

    private DebugVars() {
    }

    private static final List<DebugVar> variables = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    private static final List<Integer> marks = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    /**
     * @param descr either a simple string describing the object, or a 
     *              printf-like format string if any args are given
     */
    public static boolean add(Object obj, String descr, Object... args) {
        String msg = args.length == 0
                ? descr
                : String.format(Locale.ROOT, descr, args);
        variables.add(new DebugVar(obj, msg));
        return false;
    }

    public static List<DebugVar> get() {
        return variables;
    }

    public static void clear() {
        variables.clear();
        marks.clear();
    }

    public static boolean mark() {
        marks.add(variables.size());
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean reset() {
        if (marks.isEmpty()) return false;
        int mark = marks.remove(marks.size() - 1);
        if (mark >= variables.size()) return false;
        variables.subList(mark, variables.size()).clear();
        return false;
    }

    private static class DebugVar {
        private final Object obj;
        private final String descr;

        private DebugVar(Object obj, String descr) {
            this.obj = obj;
            this.descr = descr;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%s (%s)", obj, descr);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually only have a minor sidenote that might be interesting here. This code is clean and well-documented. I only have nitpicks (formatting, lack of braces) aside from the one thing that really "bothers" me.

As it stands, you're adding an additional entry-point to the heap, which *could* result in a memory leak. So long as you're only using this class in Debug-mode, that of course does not have very strong implications (especially if you use `reset` to clean the reference graph).

If you want to avoid this, you should look into using `WeakReference<T>` instead of keeping a direct reference to the object. Of course that implies you will need to deal with the object in `DebugVar` possibly being `null`. This doesn't really affect the code you currently have, though, since calling `add(null, "null");` does not result in any erroneous behaviour.